# vertices gets deleted automatically in orientdb

Tags: class, orientdb, vertex

I have create simple db in orientdb.
I have created class by following command.
=>create class user extends V.
Now this class with all data gets deleted automatically after one or two days. I am newbie and unable to figure out this problem.

Comment: Hi, how did you create the DB? memory or plocal? Are you experiencing the deletion of the single class or the entire DB?

Comment: Hello @IvanMainetti I have created db using storage type - plocal and database type - graph. I am experiencing deletion of all classes and edges but not whole db.

Comment: which version are you using?